# Modified Rational approximant of a polynomial (v2)

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

ok this time I will try to post only the essential information, I hope it doesn't end like the previous thread.
the objective is similar to the previous one  but now I cannot use the [Padèapproximant](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadeApproximant.html) function due to a small change in the numerator.

given the  Taylor expansion

```
gdl[z_] := t1 z + t2 z^2 + t3 z^3 + t4 z^4
```

with the coefficients

```
t1 = 1;

t2 = 1/2 (1 - q0);

t3 = -1/6 (1 - q0 - 3 q0^2 + j0);

t4 = 1/24*( 2 - 2 q0 - 15 q0^2 - 15 q0^3 + 5 j0 + 10 q0*j0 + s0);
```

and defined the coefficients $c_k$

```
w[z_] :=    (1 - z^2)^(-1/2) 
c[0] = 1/\[Pi]*Integrate[gdl[z]*w[z]*ChebyshevT[0, z], {z, -1, 1}]

c[n_] := c[n] = 2/\[Pi]*Integrate[gdl[z]*w[z]*ChebyshevT[n, z], {z, -1, 1}]
```

I need to find the coefficients $a_0,a_1 ,a_2, b_1$ of

$$R_{2,1}=\frac{a_0+a_1*T_1+a_2*T_2}{(1+b_1*T_1)}$$

so that
$$ R_{2,1} = \sum_0^4 c_k T_k  $$
where $T_k$  are the Chebyshev polynomial of order k.

Since the term $z^2$ has been switched with $2 z^2- 1$ i cannot use the Padè approximant.

disclaimer: no working minimal example after this point---------

I TRIED  to modify the solution posted by [j.m.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/279702/18859) but  1) i honestly didn't understand it completely, and thus i fail to modify it correctly 2) it doesn't work because `SolveAlways` gives a solution for $q_0$ and $j_0$ which is not what i want.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

t[1] = 1;
t[2] = 1/2 (1 - q0);
t[3] = -1/6 (1 - q0 - 3 q0^2 + j0);
t[4] = 1/24*(2 - 2 q0 - 15 q0^2 - 15 q0^3 + 5 j0 + 10 q0*j0 + s0);

gdl[z_] = (t /@ Range[4]) . z^Range[4] // Simplify;
    
w[z_] := (1 - z^2)^(-1/2)

c[0] = 1/π*
   Integrate[gdl[z]*w[z]*ChebyshevT[0, z], {z, -1, 1}] //
  Simplify

(* 1/64 (18 + 5 j0 (1 + 2 q0) - 3 q0 (6 + 5 q0 (1 + q0)) + s0) *)

c[n_] := c[n] = 2/π*
    Integrate[gdl[z]*w[z]*ChebyshevT[n, z], {z, -1, 1}] //
   Simplify
```

Compute the coefficients

```
c /@ Range[4];

R[2, 1] = (a[0] + a[1]*z + a[2]*(2 z^2 - 1))/(1 + b[1]*z);

eqn = R[2, 1] == Sum[c[k]*ChebyshevT[k, z], {k, 0, 4}] // Simplify

(* (a[0] + z a[1] + (-1 + 2 z^2) a[2])/(1 + z b[1]) == 
 1/24 z (24 - 12 (-1 + q0) z - 
    4 (1 + j0 - q0 - 3 q0^2) z^2 + (2 - 2 q0 - 15 q0^2 - 15 q0^3 + 
       5 j0 (1 + 2 q0) + s0) z^3) *)
```

Make both sides polynomials

```
eqn2 = Assuming[Denominator[eqn[[1]]] != 0,
  MultiplySides[eqn, Denominator[eqn[[1]]]]]

(* a[0] + z a[1] + (-1 + 2 z^2) a[2] == 
 1/24 z (24 - 12 (-1 + q0) z - 
    4 (1 + j0 - q0 - 3 q0^2) z^2 + (2 - 2 q0 - 15 q0^2 - 15 q0^3 + 
       5 j0 (1 + 2 q0) + s0) z^3) (1 + z b[1]) *)
```

The coefficients of the RHS of `eqn2`

```
cRHS = CoefficientList[eqn2[[-1]], z];
```

The coefficients of the LHS of `eqn2`

```
cLHS = PadRight[CoefficientList[eqn2[[1]], z], Length@cRHS];
```

Equating the coefficients and solving for `{a[0], a[1], a[2], b[1]}`

```
sol = Solve[Thread[cLHS == cRHS], {a[0], a[1], a[2], b[1]},
   Reals, MaxExtraConditions -> All] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify
```

[image]

The condition on the second solution is

```
eqn3 = Values[sol[[2]]][[All, -1]] // Union

(* {1 + j0 == q0 + 3 q0^2 && 
  2 + 5 j0 + 10 j0 q0 + s0 == q0 (2 + 15 q0 (1 + q0)) && q0 != 1} *)
```

This requires

```
Solve[eqn3, {j0, s0}][[1]]

(* {j0 -> -1 + q0 + 3 q0^2, s0 -> 3 + 7 q0 - 10 q0^2 - 15 q0^3} *)
```